# Android maps Zoom not working

Tags: android, android-maps

Here's my code. I have 2 activities. 
1. MainActivity
2. Mapsactivity. 
This zoom is not working. Except the zoom all works fine. Marker and everything

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        if(location!=-1 && location!=0) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            LatLng latlng = MainActivity.locations.get(location);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(MainActivity.places.get(location)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng), 15);
        }else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to modify this mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng), 15); as mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng), 15.0f);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `SupportMapFragment` then to enable zoom feature use this line of code :

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

and to animate camera with zooming feature use this :

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16), 5000, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the below code for it

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng("LATITUTE","LONGITUTE")).zoom(15).build();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
```